# File Picker plugin

Tags: flutter

Looking to see if anyone knows of a File Picker plugin similar to the image_picker, but for files, so that they can be uploaded from a mobile device.

Looking for a plugin or any example if anyone has done it already.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but if you write one, please share it!

Comment: @Robert check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66992040/9074190

Answer (score 2):

I started hacking this together. I got it basically working for android. [Here is the repository.](https://github.com/lucaslcode/import_file)

It actually copies the selected file to the app's temp directory and then provides the path, since there's no way I can see to get the file data from the OS to flutter.